# set 2 page breaks on html print

Tags: html, css, page-break

I want to add a blank page on printing html page. I use this class:

```
.page{
   PAGE-BREAK-AFTER: always;       
}
```

When page is printed the page breaks. The thing is I want to add another page break after this one.

I've been trying with:

```
.page{
   page-break-after: always;       
   page-break-before: always; 
}
```

But just one is set. How could I set 2 or many page breaks? Or how could I do it to add a blank page?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
<div class="page-before"></div>
<div class="page">
    <!-- page content here -->
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.page-before {
    page-break-before: always;
}
.page {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

And as long as the `page-before` div is always empty, it shouldn't be visible or affect the layout negatively.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to introduce some text into the div just to make IE not to ignore the break after. It finally gets this way:

```css
.page {
   page-break-after: always;
}
```

and the html:

```html
<div class="page">
  <!-- page content here -->
</div>
<div class="page">
  ·
</div>
```